# What is the chip with this PN?

Tags: integrated-circuit

I have one IC for which I can not find any clue for the part number (PN).

It has "BA7P16" and "5810" on it.

[image]

What manufacturer has that logo and what chip is it?

Comment: +1, always nice to see high quality photos. :)

Answer (score 4):

I think I found it by myself. It is from Alpha & Omega Semiconductor Inc. [Here](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/alpha-omega-semiconductor-inc/AON5810/AON5810-ND/3152514) take a look.

[This](https://how-to.fandom.com/wiki/How_to_identify_integrated_circuit_(chip)_manufacturers_by_their_logos/A-E) website helps.

Comment: You should complete your answer. Q1 is a dual N-channel 20V MOSFET with a common drain. Links to parts tend to dry up over time, so all we have left is what you copied and put in quotation highlight.

Comment: +1 for useful link.

Comment: As @Sparky256 says complete your answer with the relevant information and we will probably upvote it.  You could also accept it as an answer.

Comment: Can you be more explicit in your answer about the process (so the answer can applied more generally and benefit others)? For instance, was it logo search → manufacturer name "Alpha and Omega Semiconductor" → [search on Digikey for the manufacturer](https://www.digikey.com/en/supplier-centers) → [manufacturer page on Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/supplier-centers/a/alpha-and-omega-semiconductor) → search on that page for "BA7P16" and "5810" → match for "5810"? Or some other step/process? (Use [the *edit* button](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/427873/edit).) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting, I would have thought the 5810 would be the date code (58th week of 2010) and the actual part number was BA7P16

Comment: @DerStrom8 - Hi, Just FYI, here is confirmation that for this device, the top row is part of the device part number, and the second row is other info, including a date code (format not explained here), clearly not a simple YYWW format! See this [archived PDF link](http://web.archive.org/web/20110708145547/http://www.aosmd.com/res/markings/AON5810.pdf), since the link now fails on the live Alpha & Omega Semiconductor website.

Comment: Http://www.alldatasheet.com is a good resource fir searching for parts by partial part numbers.  You can find a  lot of datasheets for obsolete parts there.  I have no connection to the website.  I just use it a lot.

Comment: DOH! I was having a bad day. 58 weeks in a year would be pretty impressive!